# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object - EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

One `person` has One `Title`. (A title can be Mr. Mrs, Dr. etc). When I am trying to save this record (Code not Included), I am getting the following error.

> InnerException = {"Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
> 'dbo.Persons' with unique index 'IX_Persons_TitleId'.  The duplicate
> key value is (1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

When debugging, I noticed that the `Person` object, has the `Title` object saved within it and the `Title` object again has the `Person` object in it. It goes on and on. I think this error is due to this. Anyway, I have attached the `Model` classes and `Entity Configuration` class. There might be something o do with the `EntityConfiguration` class.  Please help

```
public class Title: Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

}

public class Person: Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int TitleId { get; set; }

    public Title Title { get; set; }
}


 public class PersonEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Doctor> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Persons");

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.HasOne(c => c.Title)
          .WithOne(c => c.Person)
          .HasForeignKey<Person>(cc => cc.TitleId)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


    }
}
```

**CODE FOR SAVING**

```
        _dbContext.Set<Person>().Add(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**HOW ENTITY IS CREATED**

```
var person = MyMapper.Mapper.Map<Person>(request);
Title title = await _titleRepository.GettitleById(person.TitleId);
person.Title = title;

 ...

_dbContext.Set<Person>().Add(entity);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Please add the code for saving

Comment: @GuruStron Added. Please have a look.

Comment: A title only has one person?

Comment: @caius I corrected that based on @ sergey's solution, but end up with the same error.

Comment: How `entity` is created? How do you get the title for it?

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated the post with the code

Comment: @Illep is change tracking enabled?

Comment: I don;t think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one to many relations, since several people can have the same title( Mr. for example). So the same title can have several people:

```
public class Title: Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

}
```

You maybe don' need db context relations at all. But you can try to change to this:

```
builder.HasOne(c => c.Title)
.WithMany(c => c.Person)
```

Or better replace all relations with this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
            {
       entity.HasOne(d => d.Title)
    .WithMany(p => p.Persons)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TitleId)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
         }
```

And check your Person db table. It can have Unique TitleId restriction that was created by your previous  context relations. Just delete this restriction if it is there.

Comment: Then how about the EntityConfiguration class ?

Comment: If you use EF core 5 you maybe don' t need it . You have to try.

Comment: I tried it and I still end up with the same error. Help ! :(

Comment: I tried out, but end up with the same error.

Comment: Did you change db context?

Comment: No and why should I change it ? and what part of it should I change ?

Comment: .WithOne(c => c.Person) to  .WithMany(c => c.Person)

Comment: Oh. yes. I made that change.

Comment: Yup. Works. I forgot to migrate. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Or try:

```
builder.HasIndex(x => x.TitleId).IsUnique(false);
```

Comment: It cannot be helpful solution, It's just a way to run away the main problem